# How to setup a Postgres extension?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In the latest release of Django (1.8), a few model fields have been added to take advantage of the Postgres data types. I am interested in [HStoreField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) and the documentation asks to setup a PG [extension](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#hstoreextension) in order to use the new `HStoreField`s in the models.

**How do I actually use this `HStoreExtension` class to perform the database extension?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`HStoreField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) docs ask you to set up the extension by adding a migration.

You can create an empty migration with the command

```
./manage.py makemigrations yourapp --empty
```

In the created migration file, you can then import the extension,

```
django.contrib.postgres.operations import HStoreExtension
```

and add it to the list of operations.

```
operations = [
    HStoreExtension(),
]
```

Once you have created this migration, you can then use the `HStoreField` in your models.

As an example, refer to [this migration file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/tests/postgres_tests/migrations/0001_setup_extensions.py) used in the Django's postgres tests. It sets up two extensions, `HStoreExtension()` and `UnaccentExtension`.

Comment: I have a handful of apps in my project, not all of them will use `HStoreField`. Should I create the migration file with `./manage.py makemigrations app1 app2 app3 app4 --empty`, or the app provided at the command line does not really matter since the operation affects the whole database? Thanks already for your support.

Comment: `makemigrations` takes a single app name (e.g. `yourapp` in my answer above), not multiple app names. I suspect that you only need to create the migration for one app, and not every app where you use `HStoreField`. However you will have to test this as I have not tried it.