# postgres hstore removed from django model, but getting error in testing

Tags: django, postgresql, hstore

I removed the postgres hstore field when I rewrote my models.

But I'm getting this error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 1: ...r(254) NULL UNIQUE, "bio" text NOT NULL, "follow" hstore NUL...
```

This follow hstore field doesn't exist anymore. I tried migrating again, but changes are already made. I used a many to many field to create following, I was just trying to learn what hstore field could do when I added it.

Does Django still think I have an hstore field?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322750/django-test-fail-at-postgres-hstore-migration) stackoverflow answer says that testing started working when hstore extension was added to template1 postgres database.  Should I just try that? But if my model doesn't use hstore, why would I need to?

**ANSWER**

Migrated all apps to zero

python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero

Deleted migration files in each app

Re-migrated all apps

python manage.py migrate

Then the tests worked